# Implement the flatMap function

Tags: scala

Disclaimer: this is a part of a homework assignment. 
I want to implement the flatMap for the custom List object. I have successfully implemented map, but I have problem with flatMap. I do not know how to flatten the List of Lists that I get from map. I do not know if I really should use map at all.

```
trait List[+A] {
  /** The first element */
  def head: A
  /** The rest of the elements */
  def tail: List[A]
  def flatMap[B](f: A => List[B]): List[B]
  def map[B](f: A => B): List[B]

  // Concatenate two lists
  def concat[B >: A](that: List[B]): List[B] = this match {
    case Empty => that
    case NonEmpty(head, tail) => NonEmpty(head, tail concat that)
  }
}

case object Empty extends List[Nothing] {
  def head = throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Empty.head")
  def tail = throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Empty.tail")
  def flatMap[B](f: Nothing => List[B]): List[B] = Empty
  def map[B](f: Nothing => B): List[B] = Empty

  override def toString = "Empty"
}

case class NonEmpty[A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A] {

  def map[B](f: A => B): List[B] = {

    NonEmpty(f(head), tail.map(f))

  }
def flatMap[B](f: A => List[B]): List[B] = {
    val a = this.map(f)
    for (x <- a; y <- x) yield y
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for disclaimer. SO should have a tag for that, or maybe they do.

Comment: they do have it, but it says it's being deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write flatMap for a list with length n. Try to solve it supposing that you have already solved it for a list with length n-1. If you can do this, then you solved the problem, because n => n-1 => ... => 1 => 0, and for 0 you already has a solution.

This kind of thinking is suitable for your List, because it is a recursive type.

You did this already with map, do the same with flatMap. Both function is a transformation from List[A] to List[B], the only difference is the tool what they can use, map has a function that converts A to B, while flatMap has a function that converts A to List[B]

Answer (score 3):

as this is a homework, I don't want to give you a complete solution, just some hints.

1. You don't need `map` to implement `flatMap` (actually it is easier to do it the other way around)
2. you have everything you need (`flatMap` takes a function that returns a `List[B]` and `List` has `concat` defined)
3. implement the `flatMap` of `Empty` first ;-)

Comment: I had accidentally not included the definition for empty list. I guess the definition for flatmap should be recursive as well. Should I be using something like match two match two cases if the function is being applied on "typeof A" or on List[A]?

Comment: What do you mean? You get a function that takes whatever type the list contains and returns a new list of another type. Why would you need to match on something there?

Comment: hmm, I dunno, i thought if I called the function recursively i would somehow need to distinguish whether the object that's it's being called on is itself a list (List[B]), or simply an object of type B

Comment: How could you call flatMap on a B?

Comment: I guess I was referring to my initial attempt where it should have produced a List[List[B]], dunno if this is even true. Really confused with this seemingly simple problem, that I could solve in an imperative fashion, but I suck at recursion. Thanks fo your comments, I cannot upvote due to low rep.

Comment: thanks for the help, i didn't know who to choose as the best answer, so I chose the one with lower rep.